# java parent construct function depend on its different child field value?

Tags: java, constructor, static

In python I can do this like

```
class A:
    x = 3
    def __init__(self):
        do_something(self.x)

class B(A):
    x = 4

B()
```

But java code can't. java static field only belong itself.

```
public class A {
    static int x = 3;

    public A() {
        do_somthing(x);  
        // because every child may do similar thing.  An depend on its own x

    }
  

public class B extends A {
    static int x = 4;

    public B() {
        super();
    }
```

But I think java can achieve same thing in a different way. (make parent construct function depend on child class field.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do_somthing(x);
```

will use the `x` variable of class `A`, since there's no polymorphism for instance or static variables.

If you want polymorphism, you can wrap the access to `x` with an **instance** method:

```
public class A {
    static int x = 3;

    public int getX () {
        return A.x;
    }

    public A() {
        do_somthing(getX ());  
        // because every child may do similar thing.  An depend on its own x

    }
  

public class B extends A {
    static int x = 4;

    public int getX () {
        return B.x;
    }

    public B() {
        super();
    }
}
```

The call to `getX()` will execute either `A`'s `getX()` (and return `A`'s `x`) or `B`'s `getX()` (and return `B`'s `x`), depending on the runtime type of the instance on which it is called.